# Javascript / SSL - should I encrypt "form inputs" before POST or GET request or SSL does it?

Tags: javascript, ssl, encryption, https, frontend

So for example, I have this piece of code:

```html
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Should I **encrypt** this before sending the request using **Javascript** (by a passphrase that user enters manually) or this is what **SSL** does?

Or which one is more secure?

Comment: As long as you're using HTTPS it'll encode everything for you. However, POST is more secure since GET params are visible in your query and might be logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I encrypt this before sending the request using Javascript (by a passphrase that user enters manually) or this is what SSL does?

That's what TLS does. HTTPS is **HTTP over TLS**.

When people say "SSL" what they really mean to say is "TLS". SSL is the older protocol that is, to put it mildly, [not great](https://robotattack.org).

If you want to be clear about it, you can just say "HTTPS" and not have to care about the SSL/TLS distinction.

> Or which one is more secure?

Any questions about relative security depend entirely on your [threat model](https://adamcaudill.com/2016/07/20/threat-modeling-for-applications).